# Google BigTable and free text indexing

Tags: bigtable

The [BigTable article](http://research.google.com/archive/bigtable.html) main example is storing web content in a big table.
Is there an article discussing how do Google index the free text ? 
Would it be right to they use BigTable under the hood? Any information about the BigTable schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can get the underlying schema. Big Table is built on top of [GFS](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/labs.google.com/en/us/papers/gfs-sosp2003.pdf) if you are lookin at file system level.

[WEB SEARCH FOR A PLANET:THE GOOGLE CLUSTER ARCHITECTURE](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/research.google.com/en/us/archive/googlecluster-ieee.pdf)
The section serving a Google query(page:23) gives you a generic idea of data is organised into buckets.

Comment: Thanks for the link.
So would it be correct to say BigTable is used for the free text index?

Comment: I'm not sure on this, from a couple of articles I read BigTable is used to store versions of data as it provides time stamp. I don't think this is a necessary feature for indexes unless you are trying to store versions on index. As they always say column oriented databases are effecient for large sparse data sets, indexes don't fall into this category.

Comment: It's interesting the Google did not publish the article about the data structure for the unstructured data. I am doubtful they use Lucene under the hood